# $scope.$on in Isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two controllers, the second one prototypically inherits from the first.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">

    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">

    </div>

</div>
```

The `ParentCtrl` has `$scope.$broadcast` while the `ChildCtrl` has a `$scope.$on` that receives from the broadcast.

I have then decided to make a directive, whose controller definition is the `ChildCtrl`.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">

    <div my-directive>

    </div>

</div>
```

So far, so good, $broadcast/$on event still working. (Correct me if I am wrong, the directive does not have a scope of its own, right? Unless you set `scope: true` as directive property, which in this case, the directive prototypically inherits from the `ParentCtrl`?)

I decided then to isolate the scope of my directive. However, I am surprised to see that $on (in the directive controller) still receives the event by $broadcast (in `ParentCtrl`).

As I understand, this should not work anymore because $broadcast propagates events downward to descendants and in this scenario the parent-child scope relationship no longer applies because of the isolate scope. Can someone explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolating the scope is done for a different reason than what you mention.  It's not to cut the child scope free from the parent scope.

It's to keep the child scope separate from other child scopes on the same level.  The following example is where isolating the scope would really shine:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">

    <div my-directive></div>
    <div my-directive></div>
    <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

In order to keep the my-directives from freely using the same scope variable between each other, you need to isolate their scope.

Basically, the child scope and the parent scope are still linked.  As a further example to demonstrate that they are still connected, you should try executing a function in an isolated child scope, and defining that function in the parent scope.  It should still run in theory.

Comment: I think a better example would be multiple directives on the same element. If they had `scope: true`, they would all share scope. Creating an isolate scope (`scope: {}`) means they couldn't interfere with each other

Comment: @Phil, Yes, that's a much better example.  I was thinking of the example given here: https://thinkster.io/egghead/understanding-isolate-scope/ when I tried to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

you where right until the part you assume the event won't work
the events are propagated to all the children, no matter the nesting level, so as long as you have a scope listening for a specific event and this event is $broadcasted that listener will be triggered if you are in need of triggering the same event and have a selective react then you might need to consider using event parameters to react differently